# Setting Parameter To Crystal report ASP.net MVC c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports

This is my code :

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Report(string id)
        {
            ReportClass rptH = new ReportClass();
            rptH.FileName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Reports\\" + id + ".rpt";
            rptH.Load();
             rptH.SetParameterValue(0, "179");
            // rptH.SetParameterValue("Center", "103");
            // rptH.SetDataSource();

            Stream stream = rptH.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
            return File(stream, "application/pdf");   
        }
```

I'm trying to passing parameter to crystal report but I got this error :

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Connexion Failed.

At this line :

> Stream stream = rptH.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);

As I think the problem is due to rptH.setParameterValue line it work's but not showing what I want.

How to fix that please.

Answer (score 0):

It seems document is not being made successfully, 
Debug you code to confirm that you have successfully made connection  to database and rptH is valid